# Django Bootstrap front end preview button effects don't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, twitter-bootstrap

I use Python `Django` to implement the web server and back-end and use bootstrap to build the front end. My website is about a research group.

In bootstrap, there is a custom button allowing to click to show and hide another element, whose source code is as shown:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" 
   href="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-
   controls="collapseExample">
   Link with href
</a>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" 
   data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-
   controls="collapseExample">
   Button with data-target
</button>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
  <div class="well">
  ...
  </div>
</div>
```

I use this button to show the abstract of the publications, whose data is collected from models.py:

```
class Publication(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60, default='Title')
    first_author = models.CharField(max_length=60, default='Authors')
    cooperative_author = models.CharField(max_length=120,                          
                            default='Authors')
    abstract = models.TextField(null=True)
    published_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=0)
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=60, default='Tag')
    pub_url = models.CharField(max_length=120, default='pub_url')
```

and the code in my view.py is:

```
def research_accomplishment(request):
    publications = models.Publication.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'research_spacecoupe/research_accomplishment.html', {'publications': publications} )
```

The code in the HTML is:

```
{% for publication in publications %}
<h2 class="blog-post-title">{{ publication.title }}</h2>
        <p class="blog-post-meta">{{ publication.published_time }} by 
<a href="#">{{ publication.first_author }}, {{ 
publication.cooperative_author }}</a></p>
            <a class="btn btn-primary" role="button"  href="{{ 
publication.pub_url }}" aria-expanded="false" aria-
controls="collapseExample" target="_blank">
          Download
        </a>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-
toggle="collapse" data-target="#{{ publication.tag }}" aria-
expanded="false" aria-controls="#{{ publication.tag }}">
          Abstract
        </button>

        <div class="collapse" id="{{ publication.tag }}">

          <div class="well">
             {{ publication.abstract }}
          </div>
        </div>
```

The result is that I can see the data has been selected into the  using inspect element tools, but I am unable to click the Abstract button to show the content.

> Solution to the problem

The problem was revealed in the inspect element tools console. In the original code, I typed "/" in the publication.tag data, which is invalid to be used as an id for div whose class="collapse", so the function did not work. Pay attention to the naming syntax.

Comment: Assuming you have successfully imported jQuery and both Bootstrap css and js. Have you enabled Bootstrap collapse?

Comment: I suppose  so because the demo button works and it still works if I directly write the hard code in HTML. Only when I want to select data from models it  failed to display the element.

Comment: Plus, the abstract I added in the django admin is embedded with HTML tag, it seems to be like plain text on the front end if do not change any settings.  Still, this problem should be taken into account after the content can be displayed.

Comment: I have solved the problem. The syntax of the id of collapse div is wrong and now it works.  Thank you friend.

Comment: Any time, if possible answer your own question explaining what was wrong and showing the solution so that others with a similar problem can see it.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me of that. I have updated the question and added the solution.